# Different .tflite file and .txt file for implementing tensorflow in the App

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow-lite

I have created .tflite file from MLKit and used used in tensor App but the App Crashes with follow error.

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 150528 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 786432 bytes.
            at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:281)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDataIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:258)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.setTo(Tensor.java:119)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:167)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:275)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:193)
            at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:181)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Following is the code of tensorFlow App.

```
 if (isQuantized) {
      numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
    } else {
      numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
    }
    d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
    d.imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your INPUT_SHAPE/INPUT_DATA is differ from Model's INPUT_SHAPE/INPUT DATA. Convert Input data into ByteBuffer in native order with exactly shape and size what model is taking input.

Comment: How can i do this . Any idea. I have created model from firebase AutoML and wants to release in tensor-flow demo.App.

Comment: Just change model into tflite and go to documentation of firebase custom model integration in android ( Firebase MLKit section ) and just follow the documentation.